# Trying to insert Base64 image to sql server database

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
 //Convert binary image file to byte array to base64 encoded string
            FileInputStream mFileInputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\basicsworkspace\\base64upload\\src\\main\\resources\\basic.png");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = mFileInputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
               bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
            byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(ba);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);  
             String insertSql = "INSERT INTO test (image) VALUES "  
                    + "("+encoded+")";  
             System.out.println(insertSql);
            prepsInsertProduct = connection.prepareStatement(  
                insertSql);  
             System.out.println(prepsInsertProduct.execute());
```

Trying to insert image to sql server and need to have the image as base64 format. I am getting below exception. Please let me know what type of datatype and how to insert image as base64 in sql server.

Output :

```
        INSERT INTO test (image) VALUES ([B@7229724f)
        java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ']' not found.
     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:1270)
     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:165)
     at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.<init>(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:111)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.prepareStatement(JtdsConnection.java:2492)
at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.prepareStatement(JtdsConnection.java:2450)
at base64upload.base64upload.App.main(App.java:70)
```

Comment: `]` not found, so add `]` to your query at the end of the values like ([B@7229724f`]`)

Comment: @ZaidYasyaf Thanks, you've made my day with this advice

Comment: Why do you want to Base64 encode the bytes first? You'll be wasting space unnecessarily.

Comment: I found base64 will work with iphone and ipad as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just concatenating string with `toString()` value of byte array. That's incorrect. You should use another approach:

```
  String insertSql = "INSERT INTO test (image) VALUES (?)";  
  System.out.println(insertSql);
  prepsInsertProduct = connection.prepareStatement(insertSql);  
  // here set your array
  prepsInsertProduct.setBytes(encoded);
```